# 'Grazie a te' o 'Ti grazie'?

Tags: pronouns

I am learning indirect object pronouns and I am wondering why in some cases the 'a + pronoun' form is used instead of the contracted form.

Are both forms used interchangeably?

As another example, I often here 'ti amo' used and not 'amo a te', but are both technically correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *ti amo*, *ti* is the direct object. It is not changeable into *amo a te*, but only into *amo te* (the same as the English “I love you”).

In *grazie a te* there is an implicit verb: *(dico) grazie a te*. In this case it's not possible to invert the position, because the “weak” pronoun *ti* can only be attached to the verb. So you can say *ti dico grazie*, but not *ti grazie*.

There is a slight difference between *ti amo* and *amo te*; the latter is more emphatic when used absolutely (I love you and nobody else). It is also mandatory when followed by some opposition: *amo te e non (add name here)*. The former is more intimate: you won't whisper *amo te* to your lover, but only *ti amo*.

Comment: Perfect answer. egreg, perhaps you might want to add something about the version with *te* or *a te* being generally more emphatic (*amo te, non tua sorella*)?

Comment: Adding to this... is 'ti ringrazio' not used in favour of 'grazie at te'?

From what I understand, 'ti ringrazio' literally means 'I thank you', right?

Comment: @pj2452 Yes, you're right, but it confirms that you need a verb for the "ti" form.

Comment: OK, understood. Thanks again, that cleared my question up.